# Disable webflux (reactive) security for actuator health endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project with WebFlux, Health actuator, and Spring security. I am trying to build custom authentication, but that authentication kicks in on health actuator endpoints as well. How can I disable it?

According to docs I implemented a custom `ServerSecurityContextRepository`, here is basic version of what it looks somewhat like:

```
@Component
class MySecurityContextRepository: ServerSecurityContextRepository {
    override fun save(exchange: ServerWebExchange?, context: SecurityContext?) = Mono.empty()

    override fun load(exchange: ServerWebExchange) = Mono.error(ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Access denied"))
}
```

According to documentation I should not be required to do any additional configuration in order to disable auth on health endpoints. Here is configuration from `application.yml`:

```
management:
  metrics:
        web:
          server:
            auto-time-requests: true
            requests-metric-name: xxx-xxx-xxx
        export:
          statsd:
            enabled: xxxx
            host: xxxxxxxxxxxx
            flavor: xxx
  endpoint:
      health:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
      web:
          base-path: /application
```

That did not work as I saw 401 from `/application/health` endpoint. So I also added it to my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig @Autowired constructor(
        private val myRepository: MySecurityContextRepository
) {
    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http.securityContextRepository(myRepository)
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/application/health").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()

        http.cors().disable()
        http.csrf().disable()
        http.formLogin().disable()

        return http.build()
    }
}
```

Despite adding this doing `curl http://localhost:8080/application/health/` results in `{"name":"xxxxxx","message":"Unknown Error","response":"401 UNAUTHORIZED \"Access denied\""}` and status code is `401` as well. How can disable authorization for my health endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after no help I started looking at the source code and turns out `ServerSecurityContextRepository` is always invoked for `HealthEndpoint` and `InfoEndpoint` so I added the logic to skip the authentication check in repository myself. You can easily do:

```
val HEALTH_ENDPOINTS = EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint::class.java, InfoEndpoint::class.java)
```

Now you can do something like:

```
            return HEALTH_ENDPOINTS.matches(exchange).flatMap { matches ->
                if (matches.isMatch) {
                    Mono.just(SecurityContextImpl(GuestAuthToken))
                } else {
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
```

That way I am not hardcoding any paths in my repository. It's not ideal but gets the job done.

Answer (score 4):

It is best to use [EndpointRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/reactive/EndpointRequest.html) to match actuator end-points as it will match your configuration. Use the reactive import (not servlet).

application.yml :

```yaml
management:
  endpoint:
      health:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /application
```

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .matchers(EndpointRequest.to("health")).permitAll()
                .and().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding spring docu [29.2 WebFlux Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-webflux) you need just to add:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class WebFluxSecurityConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/status/**")
                .permitAll().and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add all possible paths like ../health and ../health/ or even better with wildcards